# DataFrame not able to assign values to axis with Bokeh DataColumnSource

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, plot, bokeh

I do not understand why I can not assign the values to the axes, I specified every column within the source.
If someone can help me please, I would appreciate.
The data is from http://data.un.org/
(Population growth, fertility, life expectancy and mortality)
I will go work more on the plotting once I can assign the data to the axes, hence why so many columns.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_file,show,output_notebook,push_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,HoverTool,CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.layouts import row,column,gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs,Panel



df = pd.read_csv('populationIndex2.csv', skiprows=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.head()
df.columns

 source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(AF = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 
                          'Africa') & (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at 
                          birth for both sexes (years)')],
                          SA = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'South America') & 
                          (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for 
                          both sexes (years)')],
                          NA = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Northern America') 
                          & (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for 
                          both sexes (years)')],
                          EU = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Europe') & 
                          (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for 
                          both sexes (years)')],
                          CA = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Central America') 
                          & (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for 
                          both sexes (years)')],
                          As = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Asia') & 
                          (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for 
                          both sexes (years)')],
                          Oc = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Oceania') & 
                          (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for 
                          both sexes (years)')],
                          Cb = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Caribbean') & 
                          (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for 
                          both sexes (years)')],
                          year = SA.Year))

tools = 'box_select, pan'
source.column_names
output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=500,
          title='Life expectancy by continent',
          x_axis_label='Life expectancy by percent',
          y_axis_label='Years',
          tools=tools)
 #p2 = figure(plot_height=300, plot_with=500,
 #           title='')
 p.circle(x='AF', y='year', source = source, color='Yellow')
 show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

df = pd.read_csv('populationIndex2.csv', skiprows = 1)

for percent in df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Africa') & (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for both sexes (years)')].values:
    print percent
    print percent [4]

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(AF = [percent[4] for percent in df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Africa') & (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for both sexes (years)')].values],
                                      year = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Northern America') & (df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for both sexes (years)')].Year.values))

p = figure(plot_height = 300, plot_width = 500,
          title = 'Life expectancy by continent',
          y_axis_label = 'Life expectancy by percent',
          x_axis_label = 'Years',
          tools = 'box_select, pan')
p.circle(x = 'year' , y = 'AF', source = source, color = 'red')

show(p)
```

You can then apply the same approach for the other countries inside you dataframe. The `data` in `ColumnDataSource` should contains dictionaries with keys and vector values and not pandas `DataFrames`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Could you kindly explain to me why the for loops?

Comment: The `df[column].values` is an array of many elements. The percents you are looking for are on fifth position in that array so hence `percent[4]`

Comment: Thanks @Tony I honestly a bit confused as I was using iloc to access and assign variables and plot them with DataFrame, but since I try to use Boolean to assign the variables I keep get those erros.

Answer (score 0):

@Tony

I didnt see the need for a FOR LOOP as a data frames is a dict itself. Thanks for the guidance. Dictonaries are already iterated.

```
AF = df[(df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'Africa') & 
(df['Series'] == 'Life expectancy at birth for 
both sexes (years)')]
AfricaR = AF.Value.values
output: array(['53.7', '57.0', '60.2'], 
dtype=object)
```